# Using Windows.Storage in settings page in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, settings

Well while creating a windows phone only app we can use IsolatedStorage property to get or write settings. Can anyone tell me what do I have to use while creating a Windows Universal app.

Like what should be used instead of these commands:

//Used for getting settings for app

```
localsettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

//Updating setting value for app

```
if (settings.Contains(Key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (localsettings[Key] != value)
            {

                localsettings[Key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            localsettings.Add(Key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }
       return valueChanged;
```

//For getting the value

```
public T GetValueOrDefault<T>(string Key, T defaultValue)
    {
        T value;


        if (localsettings.Contains(Key))
        {
            value = (T)localsettings[Key];
        }
        // Otherwise, use the default value.
        else
        {
            value = defaultValue;
        }
        return value;
```

// And for saving the settings

```
localsettings.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` instead of `IsolatedStorageSettings`. 
Also check this post for a Sample (it's for Windows 8 Apps, but should also work with W10). 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/archive/2012/09/17/managing-settings-in-windows-phone-and-windows-8-store-apps.aspx